# input.nextLong(); is not being recognized as a symbol?

Tags: java

So obviously this is not a completed program, Im trying to do something with a couple of fractions as you can see... But, the input.nextLong(); is not being recognized as a valid symbol for some odd reason?

```js
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import type.lib.*;

public class Check04A
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  print.println("For each fraction enter its numerator/denominator,");
  print.println("pressing ENTER after each");
  print.println("Enter x");
  Fraction x = new Fraction(input.nextLong(),input.nextLong());
  print.println("Enter y");
  Fraction y = new Fraction(input.nextLong(),input.nextLong());
  print.println("Enter z");
  Fraction z = new Fraction(input.nextLong(),input.nextLong());
  print.println("Enter t");
  Fraction t = new Fraction(input.nextLong(),input.nextLong());
 }
}
```

The error I get can be seen on the following link:
http://screencast.com/t/SFTkjV62ZhvU

Thanks

Comment: Your scanner variable is called `scan`, not `input`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `Scanner` variable named **`scan`** and you are using it as `input.nextLong()` so in that sense your `input` is obviously undefined for the compiler.

You have to change it to `input`.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Fraction x = new Fraction(input.nextLong(),input.nextLong());
```

What is `input`? I think it should be `scan`

Since you initialize `Scanner` as

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You can either change

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

To

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Or you can change `input` to `scan`

Answer (score 1):

You get a not recognized error since you did declare your Scanner object as "scan" but not "input" .So java compiler cannot find an initialized object called "input". Change "input" with "scan" and compiler won't give an error of the kind.